# Image wont show when added to HTML via JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a web app and everything works good on my machine, but once I push my code on the server and run it, for some reason images I try adding to one page won't show (I have another page where I added multiple images the same way, and all images show good). This is how I am adding image.

```js
var display = document.getElementById("display");

var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.className = "classname1"
var div2 = document.createElement('div')
div2.className = "classname2"
var slika = document.createElement('img');
slika.src = "https://picsum.photos/200";


div2.appendChild(slika)
div1.appendChild(div2)

display.appendChild(div1)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row s_product_inner">
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="display">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 offset-lg-1">
      <div class="s_product_text">
        <h3 id="id1"></h3>
        <h2 id="id2"></h2>
        <ul class="list">
          <li><span>Label 3</span> : <span id="id3"></span></li>
          <li><span>Label 4</span> : <span id="id4"></span></li>
        </ul>
        <p id="id5">

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From your code, it will be create `<img src="correct_path">`. How can `correct_path` be valid image path?

Comment: correct_path is just something I put for this post, but I can for sure verify that that is the correct path. In reality it is just link to some online pic for example https://picsum.photos/200

Comment: You should use real image URL (or anything that make sense that it really is image URL) not `correct_path` in the question. For example: `https://mydomain/image.jpg`. However, I changed to `https://picsum.photos/200` and everything works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/xzbt02yc/

Comment: It works fine for me too on my computer, however, once I try running it on the server and try accessing the website from other devices images only on that page SOMETIMES wont show. (To me it looks like the pics arent loaded fast enough, and then the browser cant show them.)

Comment: Open the dev tool in your browser (F12), run the page and look at the network traffic. If there are errors when loading images they will show up there.

Comment: It says the image is loaded, here is a screenshot, the image that is important to show is img2.png, it is selected on the bottom of the pic https://pasteboard.co/s38gsvW81wCL.png

Comment: We need to know what errors you're facing. Your code, as is, [works](https://jsbin.com/nesuhanuwo/edit?js,output).

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any errors, and it sometimes works fine, sometimes not. It works completely fine on my computer, and sometimes works when I run it on the server and access a page from another device

Comment: I think it might be web browser's problem. Try everything on different computer, or other browsers, or refresh profile of your current browser (make it like new/clean install). Because from your screenshot, you said image can't log but network inspector said loaded (HTTP 200).

Comment: I tried everything on other devices and browsers and still have the same problem.

Comment: If this is the exactly same code then it is **not** the problem with the code because it's just work perfectly on every refresh/reload.

Comment: That is what I thought, do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: 1. Web browser 2. Your network (client side) 3. The server that host image file

Answer (score 0):

i just tried your code it and it works fine,you had a backtick next to

```
div1.appendChild(div2)
```

maybe you added it while writing the post

Comment: Yes, backtick was my error, I am still new to this sorry. As I said it works perfectly on my computer, the problem is when I try running it on the server and access the page from another device. To me it looks like images arent loaded on time, and thus just not shown

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).